# How can i get field from public void method?

Tags: java, inner-classes, final

I have the method

```
public String parseRootElement(InputStream xmlStream) throws SAXException {
    String name;
        try {
        DefaultHandler handler;
            handler = new DefaultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void  startElement(String uri,String localName,String qName,Attributes attributes){
                 name=qName;
                 }
                  };
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(xmlStream, handler);

            return name;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ParserConfigurationException", ex);
        }
    }
```

How can I get **qName** from **public void  startElement()** ? 
**name=qName** doesnt work, because of

> local variable input is accessed within inner class;    needs to be
>   declared final

There are a lot of similar questions but I still be dumb.

Comment: just saying, Intelij IDEA solves this problems for you by generating auxillary array variable

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? What are you trying to achieve? There are likely better ways to do it than "working around" Java's rule that anonymous inner classes can only access final variables in their containing scope but wrapping it in a variable.

Comment: This code check is the xml file from inputStream Well-formed. if "Yes" - return name of root element. If "False" - throws SAXException

Answer (score 2):

Change `String name;` to `final String[] name = new String[1];`, `name=qName;` to `name[0]=qName;` and `return name;` to `return name[0];`.

That creates an array where the result is stored in and retrieved from. By storing the result in an array lets us make the "name" variable final and thus the compiler happy.

Comment: Thank You! Interesting subtlety=)